# How do I use selenium to change the value of a input[type='range']

Tags: java, html, selenium, range, selenium-webdriver

I have a slider that uses html5 on an input
e.g.

```
<input id="sliderWidget" title="Slide me" type="range" min="1" max="1.6" step="0.3" value="1.3">
```

I have been trying to use selenium to change the slider but traditional image slider controls are not working for me.... e.g.

```
Action dragAndDrop = builder.dragAndDropBy(sliderWidget,0,30).build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Does anyone have any ideas how i can perform this incremental range change

thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

You can select the element and use the send_keys method to send it the right/left arrow keys (which should increment/decrement the input).
In Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
...
slider = page.find_element_by_id("sliderWidget")
for i in range(10):
  slider.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
```

That should increment the value by 10.

Comment: Not a bad idea - but I get `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value direct in JavaScript:

```
WebElement slider = webDriver.findElement(By.id("sliderWidget"));
System.out.println(slider.getAttribute("value"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("javascript:document.getElementById(\"sliderWidget\").value=1.5;");

System.out.println(slider.getAttribute("value"));
```

Notice that `sliderWidget` was set to *1.5* but result was *1.6*. This way you can test that `step=0.3` is working well.

Comment: This is not a realistic test. This will work even if the element is inaccessible. And more importantly it does not trigger change handlers on the `<input>`.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the most stable and cross-browser way is to perform a binary search, dragging the mouse on the slider thumb until you hit the spot.

I have Python/webdriver code for this in my blog: http://blog.usetrace.com/?p=279

Comment: That's probably the most realistic way to do this. But it's pretty much a link-only answer. I certainly wouldn't be able to figure this out without following the link.